# Monotouch custom UIView

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am hoping someone can help with this issue that I am having using monotouch with xib files.

I am trying to create a subview derived from uiview. In IB I create a class, set its type to that of my custom class, and then link all of the IBOutlets to the custom class (this is where I think the error may be, as I suspect this should be the files owner).

A IB .h file example is

```
@interface ActivityUtilityView : UIView {
UILabel *_ActivityLabel;
UILabel *_CaptionLabel;
}

@properrty (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * ActivityLabel;
@properrty (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * CaptionLabel;

@End
```

In the application code this view needs to be loaded at run time using.

```
var intptr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("ActivityUtilityView",parent_controller,null).ValueAt(0);
m_ActivityView = new ActivityView(intptr);
```

The first issue is that none of the IBOutlets are instantiated.

The second issue is that the view is being created twice, from what I can tell.

Please can anyone help?

EDIT

I have discovered that half the problem is that the outlets are not instantiated until the view is displayed.

So how can I force a subview to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works.

```
m_ActivityView = Activator.CreateInstance<ActivityUtilityView>();
var view = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("ActivityUtilityView",m_ActivityView,null);
m_ProgressView = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0) as ActivityUtilityView;
```

Creating the view using the IntPtr constructor does not instantiate the IBOutlets until the view has been displayed. This method appears to.

To clarify the issue arrose due to a race condition on background worker threads.